# Spring Integration - JDBC channel adaptar without query result

Tags: spring-integration

I have a problem when my query return null or zero result inside `ResultSet`.

I have a `int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter` with a `rowMapper`

```
<int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter query="SELECT * FROM ENGINE_LOGS WHERE COUNTRY_ID = 2 AND BUSINESS_ID = 100 and rownum &lt; 10"   
    channel="oracle.db.resultSet.engineLogs"
    update="" 
    row-mapper="engineLogsRowMapper"
    data-source="jdbcTemplate">
    <!-- Cron Time -->
    <int:poller fixed-rate="5" time-unit="SECONDS"></int:poller>
</int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>`
```

When the query return null o zero (0) result, the row mapper class or the transformer (with input-channel: `oracle.db.resultSet.engineLogs`) never call.

I need execute an update in a auxiliary database if the query not find records in database, is it possible add a router or something to fix my problem?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

That's correct. A message with `null` `payload` does not make sense for messaging system, like Spring Integration. Actually no one existing messaging protocol support `null` payload.

Hence it is standard behavior for many `result-aware` adapter to do nothing, when there is no data from the underlying system, like JDBC in your case.

The code looks like:

```
private Object poll() {
    List<?> payload = doPoll(this.sqlQueryParameterSource);
    if (payload.size() < 1) {
        payload = null;
    }
    if (payload != null && updateSql != null) {
        if (this.updatePerRow) {
            for (Object row : payload) {
                executeUpdateQuery(row);
            }
        }
        else {
            executeUpdateQuery(payload);
        }
    }
    return payload;
}
```

As you see an `update` isn't reachable when `ResultSet` is empty.

There is a hook for you to achieve your requirements. The `<poller>` can be configured with `<advice-chain>`, where and Advice is applied for the `Callable<Boolean>.call()` method in the `AbstractPollingEndpoint`. in that custom `MethodInterceptor` you can check the result of `invocation.proceed()`, which is `true` if the underlying `MessageSource` (`JdbcPollingChannelAdapter` in our case) returns a data or not.

With the `false` result you really can do that required `UPDATE` in that auxiliary database.

We have a open [issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-997), by the way, to support `null` payloads. I have an idea for the solution to use Java 8's `Optional<?>`, which can be trasparently converted to target object for nay downstream POJO service-activator, transformer, splitter etc.

Feel free to add any comments there!

**UPDATE**

> How implement this class com.service.ValidateResultAdvice ?

```
public class ValidateResultAdvice implements MethodInterceptor {

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
         Boolean result = (Boolean) invocation.proceed();
         if (!result) {
               this.jdbcTemplate.update(...);
         }
         return result;
    }

}
```

Something like that.

Comment: Can you provide me some example for <advice-chain>

<int:poller fixed-rate="5" time-unit="SECONDS">
      <int:advice-chain>
       <bean class="com.service.ValidateResultAdvice" />
      </int:advice-chain>
     </int:poller>


How implement this class  com.service.ValidateResultAdvice  ?

Comment: Can you please have a look at the example in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50129520/3127111) and tell me if that's a proper advice usage?

Comment: That’s OK, but how is it related to the current question?

Answer (score 0):

I'm in a similar situation, where upon an empty result set I need to stop that same jdbc endpoint, so here's an example using Spring Integration 5.

Spring context configuration:

```
<int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter role="jdbc-endpoint" auto-startup="false"
        data-source="dbDataSource" channel="resultSetsIn"
        query="SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ..."
        update="UPDATE ... SET ... WHERE id IN (:id)"
        max-rows-per-poll="1">

    <int:poller fixed-rate="5000">
        <int:advice-chain>
            <bean class="services.EmptySourceService" />
        </int:advice-chain>
    </int:poller>

</int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

Advice implementation:

```
package services;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.integration.aop.AbstractMessageSourceAdvice;
import org.springframework.integration.core.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.integration.support.SmartLifecycleRoleController;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;

public class EmptySourceService extends AbstractMessageSourceAdvice {

    @Autowired
    private SmartLifecycleRoleController roleController;

    @Override
    public boolean beforeReceive(MessageSource<?> source) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Message<?> afterReceive(Message<?> result, MessageSource<?> source) {
        if(result == null) {
            // empty query result logic
            roleController.stopLifecyclesInRole("jdbc-endpoint");
        }

        return result;
    }

}
```

Endpoint stopping is done as explained in [Endpoint roles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#endpoint-roles).